# Can JAWS screenreader send it's focus to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I am creating a web app that will be accessed frequently with the JAWS screen reader.

I have several instances where it would be helpful for javascript to know what piece of text JAWS is specifically focused on.

**Specific example:**

The user is reading a piece of text.  They use a key command to open up a pop-up window, where they can write a note about what they are reading.  When they close the pop-up window, I want them to return to the place where they left off.

**I have tried something like the following:**

HTML:

```
<textarea contenteditable='true' id='note'>
</textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
var focused;

function openNote() {
  focused = document.activeElement;
  $( '#note' ).show();
  $( '#note' ).focus();
}

function closeNote() {
  $( '#note' ).hide();
  $( focused ).focus();
}
```

But the code above does not do what I want.  The variable `focused` will remember a link or a button or something like that.  But not the actual text that JAWS was reading.

How do I get the exact object/text that JAWS had in focus when `openNote()` was called?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. Nor can you know whether JAWS *is* running or not at a particular moment. I wish I could, though.
So, I believe what you are doing is the best you can do to get your user back. You can try some accessible modal window plugin like [Modaal](https://github.com/humaan/modaal), it does its work quite good and returns the user in the place where he/she was before opening the modal, when it is ever possible.

Comment: I'm glad you can't tell if I'm running JAWS or not.  I don't want people to know if I need assistive technology.  That would be an invasion of privacy and probably a HIPAA violoation

Comment: Thanks @Andre Polykanine. You are correct that the browser cannot interact with JAWS. However, after some research and contacting VFO (the makers of JAWS) technical support I have found that you can write scripts for JAWS that will help it better interact with the browser. In my case, my users are going to be subscribers to a service and we could ostensibly give them these scripts to install in JAWS so that they can better use our web app and it's note taking feature. So you can get this to work, not with Javascript, but with a package of scripts for JAWS.  Not the perfect solution, but ok.

Comment: Ah yes, this you can do, but please note, if you distribute JAWS scripts, you restrict your users' screen reader choice. I've been a faithful JAWS user for nineteen years now, but other screen readers are also around nowadays. To answer the privacy question, u-hm... I mean... it's kinda weird for me to read. If I knew who and when uses an assistive technology, I could direct him/her in a more fine-grained way, I believe.